Oauth2 Accesstoken to Windows Identity
Does anyone know if that works? Can you come with an OAuth2.0 accesstoken or JWT etc... to an C# Webapi and than transform that to an Windows Identity to run for examble WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated()?
I just tried windows auth and OAuth2.0 to combine on IIS but this seems also not to work but if that other question also doesnt work I would love to hear some ideas to do this.

Do you mean you want to map the accesstoken with Windows authentication? If this is your requirement, why you don't choose ADFS?

I have already an existing Webapi with Windows authentication hosted on IIS. And now i want that clients can access api endpoints with an Accesstoken and this token i need to transform to an windows identity or  to an saml token that i can access with this an other API.

OK, if you want to use accesstoken to access a windows authentication web api, you should use ADFS, something like this
